# how to phoenix app with local path dependency to Heroku

Tags: heroku, elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to deploy 3 elixir app and 1 phoenix web app to Heroku.
My phoenix web app has dependency with 3 elixir in local path. and I want it to be that way in heroku as well.

How can I do this in heroku? someone says I can do this using [Slug](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler). But lack of information and I don't get it how to do this.
Please help

Comment: Normally it’s being done by organizing the applications into one umbrella app.

Comment: @mudasobwa ok  I set up umbrella app for my project. do I have to do "git push heroku master" in umbrella root project? or in apps/my_app_phoenix project?